# Phone stuck at boot logo, cannot wipe data/factory reset

Tags: file-system, rom, unbricking

I will explain what happened:

I opened up terminal emulator then typed `cd /system/xbinls fsc*` then `/dev/block/vold/179:17` then `mount` then my tab got stuck and then it switched off automatically.

Then I turned on my tab and again repeated the process the same thing happened but one change now it does not turn on, its stuck at boot logo. When I open recovery mode and check the system partition it says system mount failed. Trying to wipe `/data` it says "mount /data error",  for force format `/data` it says "Formatting user data fail."

Please help someone

Comment: Which Phone/Tab?
Which Android?
Root? (I assume you had root? since you were Messing in System&Dev) Regards